# How to add two sql columns together with django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have two database tables, story and storyvote where i want to extract information about the story with the highest amount of votes. Should in theory be fairly easy i guess but the way i have constructed the database table may have made it more complicated (its still possible to change its structure though).

The two database tables are designed the following way:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=2000)
    story_text = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class StoryVote(models.Model):
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    story_vote_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, related_name="votes")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.votes
```

As you can see from the model above i have a column named "story_vote_type" which is either "up" or "down".
This for example then wont work:

```
for story in s:
    print story.title + " has " + str(story.votes.all().count()) + " votes."
```

If I filter this out i have to specify either "story_vote_type=up" or "story_vote_type=down" and then im not sure how i should be storing the results and adding them up together.

How would i add the upvotes and downvotes for a specific story here ?

So far i have this code which adds the numbers together:

```
for story in s:
...     votes = story.votes.all()
...     title = story.title
...     specific_votes = 0
...     for vote in votes:
...             if (title == story.title and vote.story_vote_type == "up"):
...                     specific_votes = vote.votes + specific_votes
...             else:
...                     specific_votes = vote.votes + specific_votes
...     print story.title + " has " + str(specific_votes) + " votes."
```

All help is appriciated.

Comment: Is your code segment you just added, giving any errors?

Comment: no, it displays the correct information, so i think all i need to do is put it into a dict somehow, but im not really sure how to add a variable as a dict key or if this is a good solution at all..didnt really understand much of what you wrote in your answer, although of course i appriciate you taking the time to write a reply, i have read in the api about annotate but even with the docs i think the examples and usage in the docs are unclear and the usage is hacky and non-intuitive

Comment: Oh! My solution was for the first line in your question. Anyway, you want to add this information in a dict to pass it to the template to display it on the HTML page?

Comment: Ok. Well it was just an attempt to get what i needed done, but if its a better solution then im more interesting in doing it better. I will revisit the docs for annotation but i find it wierd that you have to read a whole guide just to add two numbers from a column in a database, so thats why i just extracted the data and thought i could store it in a dict.. that might be a bad solution though

Answer (score 0):

Going by your problem description you want to:

1. Get the StoryType with the max number of votes.
2. Get the details of the corresponding story.

This is what you do to get 1:

```
from django.db.models import Max, F
res = StoryVote.objects.annotate(max_votes=Max('votes')).filter(current_price=F('max_votes'))
```

This is how you improve 1 to get 2:

```
res = StoryVote.objects.select_related('storyVote__story').annotate(max_votes=Max('votes')).filter(current_price=F('max_votes'))
```

As for adding the upvotes and downvotes for a specific story, I think a better approach would be to have both upvote_count and downvote_count for a `Story` in `StoryType`. Just a thought, since I am not aware of the design of your code.